# How to display correct output of Sessions & Cookies in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a problem with this program of Sessions & Cookies.

Plz see the following code:-

```
<?php
session_start();    //session starts
if(! isset($_COOKIE['cnt']))
{
    @$_SESSION['nv'] = 1;
}
else
{
    @$_SESSION['nv'] += 1;
}
$val =  $_SESSION['nv'];
echo $val;
setcookie("cnt", $val, time()+30 );
echo "<h1>No. of visits=".@$_COOKIE['cnt'] ."</h1>";
if (@$_COOKIE['cnt'] == 5)
  {
  setcookie("cnt", 0, time()-30);
  session_destroy();
  }
?>
```

It is not giving the correct output.

When I run the program for the first time, it shows:

```
No. of visits=
```

Means nothing..

& when I run the program for the second time, it shows:

```
No. of visits=1
```

I want that my output should be displayed as "No. of visits=1" when I run the program for the first time. But it shows this output at 2nd time.

Do help me please..

Comment: Why the `@` in front of `@$_SESSION['nv'] = 1;`? Does setting a session var throw an error in your script? That might be the problem right?

Comment: Supressing your erros might just be your problem.

Comment: I used @ symbol to suppress warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie set by [`setcookie`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) is sent along with the HTTP response the server sends to the client and, quoting the documentation:

> Once the cookies have been set, **they can be accessed on the next page
>   load** with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

You should print the session var

```
echo "<h1>No. of visits=" . $_SESSION['nv'] . "</h1>";
```

Comment: I am assigning $_SESSION['nv'] value to $_COOKIE['cnt'] & trying to print that value.. But it shows nothing at first click & on second click it shows No. of visits=1.. Plz help